# Print x lines after a line NOT containing a string

Tags: python, text

I am trying to condense a large file and I need to eliminate the lines not containing a certain pattern. However, I need also to save to a new file a certain limit of lines after the "not-pattern" line, and to continue to read every line of the file up to find a new "not-pattern" line.

For example, to recover the first 2 records after each "non-pattern line", the input file looks like this:

```
146587678080980

1789dsdss809809 ABC1

1898fdfdf908908 ABC2

1789798709fdb80 ABC3

798789789767567 ABC4

798787576567577

178990809809809 ABC7

189890sf908908f ABC8

178979ggggf9080 ABC9

18098rrttty0980 ABC10

1mkklnklnlknlkn ABC17
```

The output file should be:

```
1789dsdss809809 ABC1

1898fdfdf908908 ABC2

178990809809809 ABC7

189890sf908908f ABC8
```

I have tried this code up to now without success:

```
limit = 2

with open('input.txt') as oldfile, open('output.txt') as newfile: 
    for line in oldfile:
        if not ('ABC'):
            line_count = 0
            if line_count <= limit:
               newfile.write(line)
            line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that is similar to your example:

```
limit = 2
with open('input.txt') as ifh, open('output.txt', 'w') as ofh:
    ctr = 0
    for line in ifh:
        if not 'ABC' in line:
            ctr = 0
        else:
            if ctr < limit:
                ctr += 1
                ofh.write(line)
```

And here's an approach that is logically more explicit:

```
limit = 2
with open('input.txt') as ifh, open('output.txt', 'w') as ofh:
    it = iter(ifh)
    while True:
        try:
            if not 'ABC' in next(it):
                for _ in range(limit):
                    ofh.write(next(it))
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track 2 states:

- one for finding the non-pattern line
- one for capturing the lines (up to a certain limit) after the non-pattern line

```py
limit = 2

with open('input.txt', "r") as oldfile, open('output.txt', "w") as newfile:
  is_capturing = False
  for line in oldfile:
    if not line.strip():
      # Ignore empty lines, do not consider them as a non-pattern
      continue
    elif not 'ABC' in line and not is_capturing:
      # State 1
      # Found the start of the non-pattern line ('ABC' not in line)
      # Enable state to capture next lines
      is_capturing = True
      line_count = 0
    elif is_capturing and line_count < limit:
      # State 2
      # Capture a certain limit of lines after the non-pattern line
      newfile.write(line)
      line_count += 1
    else:
      # Reset the state
      is_capturing = False
```

The output file should contain:

```
1789dsdss809809 ABC1
1898fdfdf908908 ABC2
178990809809809 ABC7
189890sf908908f ABC8
```

If you need to also save the "non-pattern" line, add it to State 1:

```py
    elif not 'ABC' in line and not is_capturing:
      # State 1
      # Found the start of the non-pattern line ('ABC' not in line)
      # Enable state to capture next lines
      newfile.write(line)
      is_capturing = True
      line_count = 0
```

If you want to preserve the empty lines between each written line:

```py
newfile.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
limit = 2

with open('input.txt') as oldfile, open('output.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    line_count = 0
    for line in oldfile:
        if 'ABC' in line:
            newfile.write(line)
            line_count += 1
            if line_count == limit:
                break
```

Answer (score -1):

Given the input file as this:

```
146587678080980

1789dsdss809809 ABC1

1898fdfdf908908 ABC2

1789798709fdb80 ABC3

798789789767567 ABC4

798787576567577

178990809809809 ABC7

189890sf908908f ABC8

178979ggggf9080 ABC9

18098rrttty0980 ABC10

1mkklnklnlknlkn ABC17
```

First open the file and strip the empty lines, saving the lines with content to a list of lines:

```py
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    in_lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines() if len(line.strip('\n')) > 0]
```

Then you run through all the lines to find the "non-pattern line" ids and extend an empty output list of lines with the lines up to the limit after the current "non-pattern line" index.

```py
out_lines = list()

LIMIT = 2
for idx, line in enumerate(in_lines):
    if 'ABC' not in line:
        out_lines.extend(in_lines[(idx + 1):(idx + 1 + LIMIT)])
```

To get the output file with the same format as the input:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines('\n\n'.join(out_lines))
```

The result `output.txt` should be this:

```
1789dsdss809809 ABC1

1898fdfdf908908 ABC2

178990809809809 ABC7

189890sf908908f ABC8
```

Comment: What is `input_file` and `output_file`? Because file objects are not subscriptable and have no `extend` method.